# gcloud update components - permission denied on file ...\kuberun_licenses\LICENSES.txt

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

**Start udating gcloud:**

```
Your current Cloud SDK version is: 321.0.0
You will be upgraded to version: 322.0.0

┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│        These components will be updated.         │
├──────────────────────────┬────────────┬──────────┤
│           Name           │  Version   │   Size   │
├──────────────────────────┼────────────┼──────────┤
│ Cloud SDK Core Libraries │ 2021.01.05 │ 16.1 MiB │
│ Kuberun                  │      0.0.1 │ 20.6 MiB │
└──────────────────────────┴────────────┴──────────┘
```

**I get error:**

```
╠═ Uninstalling: Cloud SDK Core Libraries                   ═╣
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
╠═ Uninstalling: Kuberun                                    ═╣
ERROR: (gcloud.components.update) Отказано в доступе: [C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Google\ct4j-cloud-sdk\LATEST\google-cloud-sdk.staging\platform\kuberun_licenses\LICENSES.txt]

Ensure you have the permissions to access the file and that the file is not in use.
```

Env: Win10

1. i try from IDEA appEngine Plugin.
2. try from CMD with admin privilegies.
   with some error

How to update this ?
Maybe you can disable Kuberun ? I use only appengine

Answer (score 7):

I solved this issue by removing the folder `kuberun_licenses` from `google-cloud-sdk\platform` path. Not the one with `.staging`.

Comment: - this worked for me when I was updating from v 320 to v 351 after few months

Comment: or remove the read-only flag

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a known issue: https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/support/21001

Here is the workaround provided at that link:

> Please run the following commands in a PowerShell window:
>
> ```
> $gcloudDir = Get-Command gcloud | Select -ExpandProperty "Source" | Split-Path | Split-Path
> attrib -r "$gcloudDir\platform\kuberun_licenses*.*" /s
> attrib -r "$gcloudDir\lib\kuberun*.*" /s
> attrib -r "$gcloudDir..\google-cloud-sdk.staging\platform\kuberun_licenses*.*" /s
> attrib -r "$gcloudDir..\google-cloud-sdk.staging\lib\kuberun*.*" /s
> Remove-Item "$gcloudDir..\google-cloud-sdk.staging" -Recurse
> ```
>
> If any of the commands fail, proceed with running the remaining
> commands.
>
> After running the PowerShell script, run the following in a regular
> Command Prompt (not PowerShell):
>
> ```
> gcloud components update --version 320.0.0
> ```
>
> Please note, after applying this workaround, do not run 'gcloud
> components update' as this will re-trigger the issue. Please wait
> until the fix is released before updating components.

Comment: The solution is out-dated.

Comment: This worked for me, except there are some missing back slashes. Tried to submit an edit but queue is full

Answer (score 0):

I find only with full reinstall solution:

- exit idea
- rename folder C:\Users\Step\AppData\Local\Google\ct4j-cloud-sdk -> _ct4j-cloud-sdk
- run idea
- start gradle -> downloadCloudSDK
- delete folder _ct4j-cloud-sdk
- profit

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did,

On Win10, I went to

**C:\Users{your user name}\AppData\Local\Google**

removed dir ct4j-cloud-sdk

And ran:

**mvn appengine:deploy**

This solved the issue for me

Comment: the trouble is that this needs to be done 2-3 times a week) each update.
thanks Google

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse,
Exit the Eclipse.
Remove the ct4j-cloud-sdk folder from gCloud installed dir.
Open the Eclipse and Deploy.

Answer (score 0):

In a windows file browser, watch file

C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk.staging\platform\kuberun_licenses\LICENSES.txt

during the gcloud components update process. It will disappear then re-appear. When it does, right click on properties and uncheck Read Only then select Ok, then confirm the administrator pop-up. You must do this quickly or have some way of slowing the update script.

Nothing else worked. This does. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

New Date. New version. New Google Cloud trouble ... crap...

```
Your current Cloud SDK version is: 322.0.0
You will be upgraded to version: 323.0.0

|        These components will be updated.         |
+--------------------------+------------+----------+
|           Name           |  Version   |   Size   |
+--------------------------+------------+----------+
| Cloud SDK Core Libraries | 2021.01.08 | 16.1 MiB |
| Kuberun                  |      0.0.1 | 20.6 MiB |
| gcloud cli dependencies  | 2021.01.08 | 10.7 MiB |
+--------------------------+------------+----------+

gcloud crashed (Error): [('C:\\Users\\USER_NAME\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\ct4j-cloud-sdk\\LATEST\\google-cloud-sdk\\platform\\gsutil\\third_party\\funcsigs\\docs\\index.rst', 'C:\\Users\\USER_NAME\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\ct4j-cloud-sdk\\LATEST\\google-cloud-sdk.staging\\platform\\gsutil\\third_party\\funcsigs\\docs\\index.rst', 'symbolic link privilege not held'), ('C:\\Users\\USER_NAME\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\ct4j-cloud-sdk\\LATEST\\google-cloud-sdk\\platform\\gsutil\\third_party\\mock\\docs\\changelog.txt', 'C:\\Users\\USER_NAME\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\ct4j-cloud-sdk\\LATEST\\google-cloud-sdk.staging\\platform\\gsutil\\third_party\\mock\\docs\\changelog.txt', 'symbolic link privilege not held')]
```

damn the updates, what to do with it, I lose one day a week with them ...